# How can I tell whether a JavaScript file has already been included in an ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, script-tag

I have an ASP.NET user control (.ascx file). In this user control I want to use a .js file.

So I include `<script src="file.js" type"text/javascript"></script>` on the page.

However, sometimes I use this user control in a webpage where this same script has already been loaded.

How can I add a `<script />` declaration that will render on the page only if the page doesn't already contain another `<script />` tag for the same script?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just include the javascript library in all pages?

Comment: jfar, I have sites that only ever need a javascript file on one particular page when I show a particular control, most of the time that control will not be used at all on that page. It would be wasteful to include javascript to be served to every user who went to every page on the site, especially if their browser insisted on requesting the file on each request.

Comment: The reason I don't want to include it in all the pages is performance: I don't need it in all of them.
Neil, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you are using asp.net, it makes sense to do the check server-side as that will be where you choose to add the reference to the javascript file. From your .ascx file you could register with the following:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("GlobalUnqiueKey", UrlOfJavascriptFile);
```

... from your page you just call the ClientScript object directly:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("GlobalUnqiueKey", UrlOfJavascriptFile);
```

The 'GlobalUniqueKey' can be any string (I use the url of the javascript file for this too)

If you try to register a script with the same key string, it doesn't do anything. So if you call this in your page, your control or anywhere else, you'll end up with only one reference in your page. The benefit of this is that you can have multiple instances of a control on a page and even though they all try to register the same script, it is only ever done a maximum of one time. And none of them need to worry about the script being already registered.

There is a 'IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(stringkey)' method which you can use to see if a script has already been included under that key but it seems pretty redundant to do that check before registering as multiple attempts to register do not throw exceptions or cause any other errors.

Doing the check client-side means that, assuming the multiple javascript references are cached by the browser (they may not be), you still have multiple  tags and the over head of each one causing some javascript to run. If you had 20 instances of your control on a page, you could get serious issues.

Comment: don't know ASP, but this looks a much nicer solution than doing it client side like I have done.

Comment: Based on your answer I built on my base page boolean properties "AttachJqery", "AttachEngine" etc.
and this controls the attatchement so I don't have to get dirty with code.
I also have the option to set defaults.
If anyonw needs example will be glad to post, please comment here.

Answer (score 6):

You can do one of two things client side...

1. Check the dom for the script tag corresponding to the javascript file your want to check
2. Test  a variable or function you know has/will be defined within the javascript file for undefined.

Here's a quick JS function which uses JQuery to do what you need:

```
function requireOnce(url) {    
    if (!$("script[src='" + url + "']").length) {
        $('head').append("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + url + "'></script>"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
I use jQuery, that would be awsome.
Thanks for all answerers, I will surely use them on the future.

Comment: One problem is, if the jQuery itself is the script I want to check :)

Answer (score 0):

use something like the following:

```
if(typeof myObjectOrFunctionDecalredInThisScript != 'undefined') {
  // code goes here
  var myObjectOrFunctionDecalredInThisScript = { };
}
```

This tests if your object or function already exists and thus prevents redeclaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
var storePath = [];
function include(path){
if(!storePath[path]){
    storePath[path]= true;
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.src = path;
    e.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
    return false;
 } }
```

use this in your main page and call  function **include** with argument javascript file name

Answer (score 0):

As you want to include javascript on one page of your site only.
If you use Asp.net(4.0) then it is very easy.
Just include following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="filepath and name here"></script>
```

in `ContentPlaceHolder` of content page.

Answer (score 0):

@Shimmy I am coming across this after a long while but maybe it might still be useful or at least help other coming from behind. To check if jquery is already loaded do this

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.x.x.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Don't miss the escape character in the closing script tag in document.write statement.

@mysomic, why did I not think of that. thumbs up

PS: I would have loved to write this right under the line where @Shimmy wrote that jQuery itself is the script he wants to load. But dont know how to write it there. cant see a reply or anything similar link. This may sound dumb but maybe I'm missing something. Pls point it out, anybody?

Answer (score -1):

If you need it from server side, and Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude won't work for you in case script was included by some other way other then Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScript (for example page.Header.Controls.Add(..), you can use something like this:

```
static public void AddJsFileToHeadIfNotExists(Page page, string jsRelativePath)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in page.Header.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is HtmlLink htmlLink)
        {
            if (htmlLink.Href.ToLower().Contains(jsRelativePath.ToLower())) return;
        }
        if (ctrl is ITextControl textControl
          && (textControl is LiteralControl || textControl is Literal))
        {
            if (textControl.Text.ToLower().Contains(jsRelativePath.ToLower())) return;
        }
        if (ctrl is HtmlControl htmlControl)
        {
            if (htmlControl.Attributes["src"]?.ToUpper()
              .Contains(jsRelativePath.ToUpper())) return;
        }
    }

    HtmlGenericControl Include = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
    Include.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
    Include.Attributes.Add("src", page.ResolveUrl(jsRelativePath));
    page.Header.Controls.Add(Include);    
}
```

Comment: Too much casting ctrl is HtmlLink, then ctrl as Html link. Consider: var lnk = ctrl as HtmlLink; if ctrl != null . Saves a cast.