# Avoid that script in MasterPage and in Iframe child page is executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have developed a script with jQuery that everytime a `<select>` selection is changed then some logic is executed.

Initially I added that script to the `MasterPage`, in order to be sure that every page would be considered - however, I have some external pages (`aspx`) that do not use the `MasterPage` and, as consequence, don't have the script.

To solve this I added the same script to a custom control, that is rendered as a `<select>` and is also present in those external pages. Unfortunately in this way the script is executed twice, instead of just once.

How can I change my code in order to ensure that the script would be executed in every page, but just once?

Answer (score 1):

user .net's ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude, it has a key parameter, so it will only register each key once.  In your masterpage and user control, just make sure you register them using the same key.

You could also use jquery to see if it is already registered and add id:

```
function requireOnce(url) {    
    if (!$("script[scr='" + url + "']").length) {
        $('head').append("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + url + "'></script>"); 
    }
}
```

above was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908425/how-can-i-know-if-a-javascript-file-has-already-been-included-in-a-top-level-page)

Comment: The problem is that the MasterPage comes from a Legacy tool, therefore I cannot edit its codebehind, but only the MasterPage.master file. Therefore I inserted in the master page : <% if (Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("myScriptID") == false) { %> $(document).ready(function() { //here the script } <%} %> And in the custom control the same, using same ID for the script key. I do not use the ClientScriptManager, since I do not use an UpdatePanel. But even with this solution it does not work, the script is executed twice.

Comment: what if I want to include jQuery?

Comment: if jquery is the included file in question, you may have to check the <head> in your code behind of your user control to see if it is already included.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I tried to follow your suggestions, but my case is a bit trickier since I have Iframes inside MasterPage's placeholders.
Therefore if I check "Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered" within one custom control (in one child page) the script is correctly inserted just once in the Iframe, but anyway inserted even if already present in MasterPage.

Comment: I inserted the code above both in MasterPage (MP) and in customControl (ascx file). In MP I check the existence of the inner iFrame and wait until is loaded to check if in the page the same script is registered or not. By the way it seems the condition "(!$("script[scr='" + url + "']").length" does not match, since scripts are still inserted twice or more, considering they are inserted once for every customControl.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the encapsulating control which includes the script then remove the original script from the `Master` and use the said control in both pages. Unless I missed something, this is to say:

- Remove original script from `MasterPage`
- Use custom control with script in `MasterPage`
- Use custom control with script in non-mastered pages.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't want asp.net to handle my JavaScript, so I created a global variable `isPostBack` and set it to false by default. When the page did his postback I added `window.isPostBack = true;` to the page. Now your javascript only has to check the global variable (`if(window.isPostBack){...}`).