# Is there a multiple inclusion guard for javascript/jquery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on my first ASP.NET MVC 3 application with utilizes some JavaScript and jQuery here and there.  I ran into a problem with a particular jQuery plugin that ended up being referenced multiple times and this resulted in a stackoverflow/too much recursion error when I tried to use the plugin on the page.  Moving this out of my partial view file and into the `_Layout.cshtml` caused the error to go away, but I'm thinking this isn't really the solution either.

I'm still very new to JavaScript and jQuery and was wondering if there's a guard, like I would use in a C file to avoid multiple includes of a particular header file, to do likewise with a JavaScript file.

Or, if there's a better way to handle this, I'd be interested in hearing how.  Perhaps it is an issue just with this particular plugin file.  Any guidance on this?

Comment: Closing this as it's pretty much a duplicate of another - just missed it during my searching.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I know if a javascript file has already been included in a top-level page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908425/how-can-i-know-if-a-javascript-file-has-already-been-included-in-a-top-level-pag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the code below to solve a similar issue.

```
function requireOnce(url) {    
if (!$("script[src='" + url + "']").length) {
    $('head').append("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + url + "'></script>"); 
}
```

}

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908425/how-can-i-know-if-a-javascript-file-has-already-been-included-in-a-top-level-pag/908443#908443)

### Option 2

I just found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724166/mvc-registerclientscriptinclude-registerclientscriptblock/3630757#3630757). I've yet to try it but if you are using razor it sounds like it could be perfect. I'll have to try this myself.

Comment: Thanks - missed the original question.

Comment: It's understandable, most of the results that are returned are for the RegisterClientScript which only works in webforms. Also, I had to go through a few other versions of similar scripts before I found one that works, so hopefully it works for you.

Comment: NB: Small typo in the 2nd line where it says `scr=`